# CakePHP adding multiple HABTM rows and appending them to the Form

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have 2 entities: `Product` and `List`. They share a **HABTM** relationship.

Lets say I have about 1000 `Product` entries and I am currently creating a `List`. In the `Form`, I will add multiple `Product` to the `List`.

First question:
Since 1000 Products is a lot, it would not be wise to use a `<select>` tag to list them. So I'm going to use a text input and validate. This validation can be done by an AJAX request, but I was thinking if using `Validation::inList()` (from http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#core-validation-rules) would be better?

Second question:
In order to add multiple `Product` to the list, I'll probably need something like and 'Add Product' button, to append the new row to the Form. The question is, how would I insert the entry in the `ListsController`? also what `name` will the **JS-generated** `input` should have

Comment: Why don't you use an AJAX autocompleter to select which product to add to the list? Then you will add a record in your relationship table (e.g. table named ListProducts) with list ID and product ID for each product (in each list)

Comment: I am new to cakePHP, so I dont know every class. Is that a cakePHP class (if so, could I get an example please?) or do you mean that I create an ajax request?

Comment: I suggest you read some tutorials. You will create a Product model, a List model and a ListProduct model to link instances of the two together. Your autocomplete will be a plugin - Google ajax autocomplete